# How can I access cached (flash) files within Google Chrome Extension webRequest?

Tags: flash, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I'm using http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onHeadersReceived to be informed about any flash files getting loaded.
However, if the flash file is already in the Google Chrome cache, it doesn't show up anymore in this listener.

Any idea how to get notified about any flash file requested/needed within a specific website?

Comment: I even tried handlerBehaviorChanged() to flush the cash before adding the event listener. But still, the flash files do not show up (except if I clear the browser cache manually). As far as I know, this function clears the in-memory cache only. Perhaps, the problem is within the on-disk cache?